# How to convert xsl-fo to docx (Office Open XML) in Java?

Tags: java, xsl-fo, docx, apache-fop

I'm looking for an open-source or commercial friendly library in Java to convert `xsl-fo` to `docx` (Office Open XML) format.

I'm planing to use `xsl-fo` to produce `pdf` documents (with Apache FOP), so I thought generating Word documents (`docx`) out of the same source XML could be a good idea.

**UPDATE**: I forgot to mention that I'm using Java.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could do: your source xml -> docx -> xsl-fo -> pdf.

or easier perhaps: source xml -> Flat OPC XML -> xsl-fo -> pdf.

Once you have a docx (or a Flat OPC XML document), transforming that to PDF via FOP is easy with docx4j (since you mention FOP, I'm assuming Java is ok for you).

The benefit of this approach is that you style your output docx as desired, and get the xsl fo "for free".

Flat OPC XML is convenient, because it is docx as a single XML file (ie no need to unzip).  So you can create it easily via XSLT.  To see it, create a document in Word 2007, and choose "save as .. xml".

Comment: There is http://www.xmlmind.com/foconverter/what_is_xfc.html (and there may be others) but note that my suggestion was you go docx to XSL FO instead. Was there something about that which you didn't like? :-)

Comment: I should have mentioned you can also get HTML output using the approach I suggested.