# XSL:FO to DOCX conversion in Java

Tags: java, xml, openxml, xsl-fo, docx

I need to find a java API tool for converting XSL:FO *.fo files to OOXML *.docx format. I understand *.fo -> *.docx transition is quite hard due to OOXML specification. 
I couldn't find any working freeware solutions. 
I am prepared to spend quite some money for the global enterprise license. So far I found:

- [XMLmind XSL-FO converter](http://www.xmlmind.com/foconverter/)
- Ecrion's [XF Rendering Server](https://www.ecrion.com/ecrion-develop)
- myfop - Apache FOP based approach from myfop.blogspot.com - download doesn't work...

Do you know any other tools with java APIs that perform *.fo -> *.docx transformation? Are there any freeware solutions?

I do not want to develop a new processor due to complexity of OOXML specification. I am looking for both freeware and commercial solutions, but so far I managed to find only 2 mentioned.

Similar question(unanswered) - [How to convert xsl-fo to docx (Office Open XML) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372043/how-to-convert-xsl-fo-to-docx-office-open-xml-in-java)

Comment: What is the system producing the XSL:FO files?  Are you able to work with that system and make changes?  If so, perhaps you can avoid the XLS:FO->DOCX conversion and jump straight to DOCX at that point or possibly see other options.

Comment: XSL:FO are made using XSLT on XMLs with data and then FO files are used to produce *.pdf output(Apache FOP). I need the same visual output for *.docx files. 

Currently I use following transition: XSL:FO -> RTF -> DOC(X), but there are always some losses in the conversions.

Comment: The only suggestions I have are to try JODConverter to see if that provides a better RFT->DOC(X) transform than you are currently using.  Docmosis & JODReports are use similar technologies, but you would get most benefit from them if you used them instead of the XML->FO.  They would give you template+data -> PDF/DOC/DOCX